# how to do pinch zooming in window8 slate

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

How can I Zoom-In or zoom out multiple times in windows8 slate.

Can you please provide the answer in C#.

Thanks,

Nagarjuna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
    <!-- Put the GridView for the zoomed out view here. -->   
</SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>

<SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
    <!-- Put the GridView for the zoomed in view here. -->       
</SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
```